# Bash extract data from a XML

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

i'm creating a simple bash script and I have this problem:
I have a variable with a XML as a result from curl call

```
CURL_RESPONSE="...</param-value></params></operation><error code="ERR-M001"><msg>errore prova</msg></error></operation-result>.."
```

I need to extract the value of error code, in this case ERR-M001, and put it in another variable.
How I can do it with sed or awk?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this sed command

```
var=`sed -r 's/.*error code=.([^"]+).*/\1/g' file_name `
```

**Another way:**

```
var=`cut -d'"' -f3 filename`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below grep command,

```
var=$(command | grep -oP 'error *code="\K[^"]*(?=")')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below

```
$ echo $CURL_RESPONSE
<params><param-value>123</param-value></params></operation><error code="ERR-M001"><msg>errore prova</msg></error>
$ var=`echo $CURL_RESPONSE | sed 's/\(.*<error code="\)\(.*\)\(\">.*\)/\2/g'`
$ echo $var
ERR-M001
```

Comment: Groping 1 and 3 is unnecessary .which pattern you require group that pattern its enough.  This also give the same result `sed 's/.*<error code="\(.*\)\">.*/\1/g'`